# ВК бот не отвечает на сообщения

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Бот не отвечает на сообщения.

Зарегистрировал бота как сообщество, `Long Poll` включил, права администратора в беседе дал, при создании ключа также выдал полный доступ. В терминале приходит сообщение "тест", то есть он получает сообщения, но не отвечает.

Также добавил работу с Google таблицами, в терминале всё также работает.

***Код:***

```py
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
import vk_api
from datetime import datetime
import random
import time
import data
import httplib2
import apiclient.discovery
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'creds.json'
spreadsheet_id = ''
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    CREDENTIALS_FILE,
     ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
httpAuth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = apiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http = httpAuth)


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='')
session_api = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 193738804)


def send_message(session_api, peer_id, message=None):
    session_api.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id, message=message, random_id=random.randint(-2147483648, +2147483648))


while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            print('тест')
            if event.from_chat:

                if event.obj.text == '/рн':
                    send_message(session_api,peer_id=event.obj.peer_id, message='test')
                    values_week = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
                        spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
                        range='AW2:AW36',
                        majorDimension='COLUMNS'
                    ).execute()
                    send_message(session_api,peer_id=event.obj.peer_id, message=values_week)
```

Answer (score 0):

В функции `send_message` Вы игнорируете аргумент `peer_id`, который к тому же неправильно получаете.

`peer_id` хранится в `event.obj['message']['peer_id']`.
<sub>*Long Poll v5.103*</sub>

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id

def send_message(api, peer_id, message):
    api.messages.send(
        peer_id=peer_id, 
        message=message,
        random_id=get_random_id(),
    )

...

send_message(api, peer_id=event.obj['message']['peer_id'], message='Test message')
```